# Firebase push notification decrease sends message

Tags: firebase

My notification sends on firebase suddenly decrease from over 30,000 to 700 in a few days. My active user is over 50,000 users. I did not update my application anymore. I dont know why.
https://ibb.co/fCcSzBY
https://ibb.co/c3TryXp

Answer (score 0):

I have decrease (to 5 times) back users for Firebase notifications from 2019-04-16 for now. I got messages and can click it.

Comment: So what about now. Did you can send message for all users?

Comment: I am sending for all now (I delete errors users from subscribers). I get result w/o error. I do not know who does not get notification from my list, but not all users view my notifications.